# Interaction smart contract and third-party app : How to make sure the request comes from the original contract?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain

I'm working on a blockchain project where I need to access data stored outside the smart contract.

The smart contract own a RSA keypair (one public and one private key).
We want the private key to be stored by the community, to do that we use shamir secret sharing. So each member will have a part of the private key.

To do some operations the smart contract need to collect the pieces of keys. He need to ask the community to give their key pieces.

We want the process to be totally secured, and for this, each member of the community need to determine is the request to get the piece of key come from the original deployed smart contract or not.

Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: `The smart contract has a private key` - you mean, the smart contract's owner (account used for deploying it) has a private key.

Comment: `which is stored by our community` - well it's hardly private in that case, don't you think?

Comment: `I need to find a way to authorize the access only is the get request come from the original smart contract` - you're gonna have to rephrase that.

Comment: I updated my post, I hope it's clearer like that.

Comment: Well the question is still unclear. Your contract is public. It's address and functions are public. All you need to do is to add a function which can be called only by members of the community. And for that, you will need a `mapping` which contains the addresses of permitted callers, and a function which allows you (and you only) to add/remove callers. By the way, keep in mind that although only permitted members will be able to call this function, everyone will be able to see the data passed to it (and stored in your contract I suppose). Not sure how that works with your idea for security...